# Isotope - Insert hidden elements bug

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope 1.5.14 and I am trying to insert content with a filter by categories.

This works perfectly fine if the elements to insert are from the category X and my elements have been filtered by X.

But if I try to insert elements from category X and that my elements have been filtered by Y the callback of the insert function won't work!

Although the elements are well inserted, once I filter by X again, they will show.

After attempting to debug Isotope, I think the problem occurs when isotope gets the `$newFilteredAtoms`
which is empty because the item I am adding does not belong to category Y.

This empty array is transfered as an argument to

```
instance._revealAppended( $newFilteredAtoms, callback );
```

that calls

```
instance._processStyleQueue( $newAtoms, callback );
```

And the following code exits the function before the callback is executed,

```
var i = 0,
    testElem = this.styleQueue[0].$el,
    styleObj;

// get first non-empty jQ object
while ( !testElem.length ) {
    styleObj = this.styleQueue[ i++ ];

    // HACK: sometimes styleQueue[i] is undefined
    if ( !styleObj )
      return;

    testElem = styleObj.$el;
}
```

Any idea why? This would be very useful.

Thanks!